# Foreach loop inside array/object

Tags: javascript

I don't have a good understanding of Javascript, so I don't know if I even formulated my question properly. 
If I have an array with objects, how do I populate and replace this 'values' with mydata values? I need some sort of foreach loop, I don't know how many objects there will be.

```
editor.addButton( 'gavickpro_tc_button', {
            fixedWidth: true,
            values: [
            {
                text: mydata.knjiga,
                value: mydata.shortcode,
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent(this.value());
                }
            },
            {
            text: mydata.knjiga2,
                value: mydata.shortcode2,
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent(this.value());
                }
            }
            {
                text: mydata.knjiga3,
                value: mydata.shortcode3,
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent(this.value());
                }
            }
            ]
});
```

mydata looks like this

```
[Object, Object, Object]
   0: Object
   id: 10
   knjiga: "Something 1"
   shortcode: "some value 123"
   __proto__: Object
1: Object
   id: 12
   knjiga: "Something 3"
   shortcode: "some value 12345"
   __proto__: Object
2: Object
   id: 13
   knjiga: "Something 3"
   shortcode: "some value 1235678"
   __proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw JavaScript doesn't have foreach loop: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp. To iterate over each element in array you can use for loop as below:

```
for (i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    object= objectArray[i];
    object.knjiga = "Best book";
}
```

In jQuery is function each: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ and realize the foreach loop.